# vim automation ex commands

Tags: vim, batch, automation, script

Yeah, I know, I could just use sed. But lets assume I'm some sort of sicko. A masochist if you will..

I have a file, `/tmp/a.script`, containing:

```
%s_"taxonomy\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.taxonomy_g
%s_"rtf\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.rtf_g
%s_"csv\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.csv_g
%s_"xml\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.xml_g
```

(I snarfed them from my vim history)

I would very much like vim to execute those commands against a file, say `example.html`.

But, I can't figure out how to execute this script against the file.

I'm aware of the `-c` command line argument. But it only executes a single command, I want to execute all these commands.

Any ideas?

Answer is below, for reference, a quick sed way to do it would be:

```
for i in *.html ; do
  sed -i'' -e 's_"taxonomy\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.taxonomy_g'  $i
  sed -i'' -e 's_"rtf\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.rtf_g' $i
  sed -i'' -e 's_"csv\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.csv_g' $i
  sed -i'' -e 's_"xml\.php[^"]*\([0-9]\)_"\1.xml_g' $i
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: Notes on the `sed` example: 1) `-i''` is equivalent to `-i` due to the way Bash processes quotes; 2) You can give `-e` multiple times, or separate the `s///` commands with semicolons, to avoid multiple sed calls; 3) You can give `*.html` directly to sed.

Comment: The quotes, I got into the habit of doing that a while back, I'm running ZSH, I might have gotten some funny behavior before with that. Your comments about sed are spot on, I would have done it that way but wanted to have a more easily understood example. Not everyone is a grawity ninja!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`:source`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:source)?

```
vim example.html -c "source /tmp/a.script"
```